# show that $cf$ is Lebesgue integrable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

From H.L.Royden's Real Analysis,

[image]

Here They haven't shown how to prove $cf$  and $f+g$ is integrable.

The definition of integral and proposition $8$ given as: [image]

Using this my proof of $\int_E cf=c\int_E f$ :

\begin{eqnarray*}\int_E cf &=& \sup_{h \leq cf}\int_E h \\&=& \sup_{\frac{h}{c} \leq f}\int_E h \\ &=& \sup_{h^{'} \leq f}\int_E ch'(letting \frac{h}{c} = h^{\prime}) \\&=& \sup_{h^{\prime} \leq f} c\int_E h\\ &=&c\int_E f \\ \end{eqnarray*} is this correct?

Second thing Tell me how to show $cf$ is integrable.

Definition given:A measurable function $f$ is said to be integrable over 
$E$ if $f^+$ and $f^-$ are both integrable over E.

I was trying show $(cf)^+$ and $(cf)^-$ is integrable.$f$ is integrable implies $f^+$ and $f^-$ is integrable.But I am uanble to use this to show the required..

Answer (score 1):

The way such a proof goes is :

If $f$ is a simple function : $f=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i1_{A_i}$ where $A_i$ are measurable. Then $$\int cf=\sum_{i=1}^nca_im(A_i)=c\sum_{i=1}^n a_im(A_i)=c\int f.$$

If $f\geq 0$, then there is a sequence of simple function s.t. $f_n\nearrow f$. Then, $$c\int f=c\lim_{n\to \infty }\int f_n=\int cf_n=\int cf,$$

where the last equality comes from the fact that $(cf_n)$ is a sequence of simple function s.t. $cf_n\nearrow cf.$

Finally, if $f$ is measurable, then $f=f^+-f^-$ and $cf=cf^+-cf^-=(cf)^+-(cf)^-$, and use the previous step.

Comment: Is what i have done is correct?

Comment: @mathstudent: Now, the first equality is even wrong. Moreover, you can adjust some detail. But even, if you didn't prove that the result hold for at least simple function, it still wrong. The way you should write is : if $f\geq 0$ and $S$ is the set of simple function : $$\int cf=\sup_{ch\in S, ch\leq cf}\int ch=\sup_{h\in S, h\leq f}\int ch\underset{(1)}{=}\sup_{h\in S, h\leq f}c\int h=c\sup_{h\in S}\int h=c\int f,$$ where (1) has to be justify.

Comment: and how to show that $cf$ is integrable?

Comment: @mathstudent: You don't need integrability to prove that $\int |cf|=|c|\int |f|$. One you proved that, have $f$ integrable yield $cf$ integrable.

Comment: Actually in  the question we are asked to show $cf$ is integrable..So How can we show that using $f$ is integrable?

Comment: First prove that $\int|cf|=|c|\int |f|$ as I show you previously (or equivalently that $\int cf=c\int f$ for all positive function and $c>0$. Thus, integrability of $cf$ follow. Notice that integrability of $cf$ is useful for the last step only (i.e. when you make a decomposition of $f$ as $f^+-f^-$).